# jQuery on Context Menu Web Forms

Tags: jquery, html, webforms

Pretty new to jQuery, I am trying to add a right-click menu to a Web Forms application on the
     `div id = "category"`
After much googling, I have come up with this, but doesn't work:

HTML:

```
 <div id ="category">
    <span class="categoryheading">
        <span id="catHide<%#Category %>" class="hidecategory" onclick="$('.cat<%#Category %>').hide(); $('#catHide<%#Category %>').hide(); $('#catShow<%#Category %>').show();">
        </span>
      <span id="catShow<%#Category %>" style="display: none;" class="showcategory" onclick="$('.cat<%#Category %>').show();  $('#catShow<%#Category %>').hide(); $('#catHide<%#Category %>').show();">
        </span>
    <%#Eval("GroupName").ToString() != "" ? Eval("GroupName") : "No Category" %>
   </span>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
  // Allow context menu on Category
        $("#category").contextMenu({
            items: {
                ExpandAll:{
                    name: "collapse",
                    title: "Collapse All",
                    alert: ("Test - It Works!!")},
                CollapseAll:{
                    name: "expand", 
                    title: "Expand All",
                    alert: ("Test - It works")}
            }
        });
```

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a context menu using [`JQuery-contextify`](https://github.com/abeMedia/jquery-contextify).

**Code :**

HTML :

```
<div id="menu">
  Hello
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var options = {items:[
  {header: 'Options'},
  {text: 'First Link', href: '#'},
  {text: 'Second Link', onclick: function() {}},
  {divider: true},
  {text: 'Stuff', href: '#'}
]}
$('#menu').contextify(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Léo Martin    I get the message that Object doesn't support property or method 'contextify'"  ("AddEventListener" won't work either.)